# Android data download with location manager

Tags: android, synchronization, android-asynctask, locationmanager

Is there a way I can synchronize when I get the location from the locationManager and the data I download from a webpage? The data are Hotels for which I calculate distance (that's why I need the location).

I start the location manager and I start the download in onCreate method, but I never know which one will be finished first so that I can calculate the distance of those Hotels. Also I have set listener on the AsyncTask so that the activity get's notified when the the data is downloaded.

The solution I have now is that I start the locationManager and when I get the location I start the download. I think if I could start this paralelly and somehow get notified when both are finished I could reduce the loading time.

Comment: i don't understand how you can start the download without knowing the location around which to search.

Comment: I'm downloading data from an XML file for the web from which I create objects...this data is a list of hotels which have latitude and longitute...then I calculate the distance with my location (latitude and longitude) that I got from the location manager.

Comment: ok. then i don't understand what your issue is. you have 2 callbacks, one for download, one for location, when each is called, test if the other was called, if so, do your stuff

Comment: oh well... I thought more about if there exists a good practice for such cases...let's say when I have 4 AsyncTasks...in every callback I should check if the others were set... that's would not really one of the best solutions.

Comment: If you have 4 asynctasks, that's easy. you use a 5th thread that calls get on each asynctask in any order. it would act mostly as a Thread.join. In the case of callbacks, a simple counter could be sufficient

Comment: aha...do you have somewhere a code example for a situation like this?